# VPN client on Windows 10 to connect to multiple server at the same time

Tags: remote-access, vpn

I would like to connect to multiple server at the same time to monitor multiple server (>3) without disconnect/connect.

For the moment, I'm using **Sophos SSL VPN Client** with 3 different configurations. I can only be connected one at a time.
To have a simultaneous connection, I'm using also **SonicWall Global VPN Client**.
I can only have 2 connections at the same time, I would like a least 3.

I have no money restrictions. I'm looking for a software that can allow to have multiple connection at the same time. I prefer not to use VM's. I'm aware that multiple opened connection is a security risk. Network and VPN are not my specialty, but I can manage to edit my router configuration if needed.

The purpose is to jump from one RDP to another with one clic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Viscosity](https://www.sparklabs.com/viscosity/) seems to do the trick. I just can't manage how to import a .rcf file from SonicWall. However I succeed to have 3 simultaneous connection with Viscosity thanks to the Split DNS option a priori.

In fact I had to deactivate DNS mode.

Comment: Please accept your own answer. Doing so will help others who read this question in future